# How to add a new c source file to openssl project

Tags: c, openssl

I wish to add a new source code file to the openssl project (some custom memory checks). What and where do I have to change in the configure and/or Makefile ? I am quite new to this. Thanks for your help

Comment: To be brutally honest: You shouldn't. If you can't even figure out how to add a single source file then the likelihood that the code you want to add is good, safe and without security holes is quite small I'm afraid.  "Quite new to this" isn't very assuring either. I'm sorry.

Comment: ^ditto. Messing with crypto/security code which have been verified by thousands of peer-reviewers and still eventually being buggy is a bad idea even for professional.

Comment: This comment is a bit severe. I have detected a few serious bugs in this projet in 2014 ( crypto/ui/ui_lib.c:919 in openssl-SNAP-20140703). Any help would be welcome.